Crear Template huella digital 4500 Digital Persona
Intento generar un "Template" pero siempre me da error al añadir la cuarta huella.
Dejo un código simplificado que entiendo debería funcionar.
En mi código real tengo las 4 huellas almacenadas y son diferentes.
Solo encuentro como explicación "Failed" para "Enrollment.TemplateStatus = 2"
Gracias a quien me pueda orientar.
Private Sub DPFPVerificationControl1_OnComplete(ByVal pFeatureSet As Object, ByVal pStatus As Object)
Dim Enrollment As DPFPEnrollment
Set Enrollment = New DPFPEnrollment
Dim Template As DPFPTemplate
Set Template = New DPFPTemplate
Enrollment.Clear
Enrollment.AddFeatures pFeatureSet
Enrollment.AddFeatures pFeatureSet
Enrollment.AddFeatures pFeatureSet
   If Enrollment.FeaturesNeeded <> 1 Then
      Stop
      End If
Enrollment.AddFeatures pFeatureSet
   If Enrollment.TemplateStatus = 2 Then
      Stop  '  <-- Siempre se detiene en este STOP
      End If
   If Enrollment.FeaturesNeeded <> 0 Then
      Stop
      End If
Set Template = Enrollment.Template
End Sub

